# Solve works with numbers but not number stored in variable

Tags: equation-solving

I have the code:

```
theta = 0.1; phi = 0.1;
a = 1 - 3 Sin[theta]^2*Cos[phi]^2;
b = 1 - 3 Sin[theta]^2*Cos[phi - (2 Pi/3)]^2;
c = 1 - 3 Sin[theta]^2*Cos[phi - (4 Pi/3)]^2;
Solve[
  a*b*Sin[(Sqrt[3] x - 3 y)/2] == 
  a*c*Sin[(Sqrt[3] x + 3 y)/2] == 
  -b*c*Sin[Sqrt[3] x], 
  {x, y}]
```

which I left running for 10 minutes before aborting. However if I simply replace the constants with their numerical values, aka I replace the last line above by

```
Solve[
  0.965496 Sin[(Sqrt[3] x - 3 y)/2] == 
  0.960503 Sin[(Sqrt[3] x + 3 y)/2] == 
  -0.984803 Sin[Sqrt[3] x], 
  {x, y}]
```

The above runs straight away with no problems. I don't understand why it is doing this. Any pointers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `Solve` is having trouble with the mixture of exact and inexact numbers you are feeding it. If you make all the number exact or all inexact, it is a lot happier and quicker. I think it best to make all the numbers exact and apply `N` to get a numerical result after the solutions are found. `Chop` is needed to get rid of some numerical evaluation fuzz of the form `u + 0. I v`.

```
theta = 1/10; phi = 1/10;
a = 1 - 3 Sin[theta]^2*Cos[phi]^2;
b = 1 - 3 Sin[theta]^2*Cos[phi - (2 Pi/3)]^2;
c = 1 - 3 Sin[theta]^2*Cos[phi - (4 Pi/3)]^2;

Solve[
  a*b*Sin[(Sqrt[3] x - 3 y)/2] == 
  a*c*Sin[(Sqrt[3] x + 3 y)/2] == 
  -b*c*Sin[Sqrt[3] x], 
  {x, y}
] // N // Chop
```

> ```
> {{x -> ConditionalExpression[7.2552 C[1], C[1] ∈ Integers], 
>   y -> ConditionalExpression[-4.18879 C[2], C[2] ∈ Integers]}, 
>  {x -> ConditionalExpression[7.2552 C[1], C[1] ∈ Integers], 
>   y -> ConditionalExpression[-0.666667 (3.14159 + 6.28319 C[2]), C[2] ∈ Integers]},
> ...
>  {x -> ConditionalExpression[1.1547 (-2.08165 + 6.28319 C[1]), C[1] ∈ Integers], 
>   y -> ConditionalExpression[-0.666667 (-0.00462451 + 6.28319 C[2]), C[2] ∈ Integers]}}
> ```

It is likely you will want to get a set of solutions for specific values of `C[1]` and `C[2]`, say `C[1] = 1` and `C[2] = 2`. That can be done with

```
With[{m = 1, n = 2}, 
  Replace[
    Replace[sol, {C[1] -> m, C[2] -> n}, ∞], 
    ConditionalExpression[u_, _ ∈ Integers] -> u, ∞]]
```

which for the above solution returns

> ```
> {{x -> 7.2552, y -> -8.37758}, {x -> 7.2552, y -> -10.472}, 
>  {x -> 5.4414, y -> -7.33038}, {x -> 5.4414, y -> -9.42478}, 
>  {x -> 9.069, y -> -7.33038}, {x -> 9.069, y -> -9.42478}, 
>  {x -> 10.8828, y -> -8.37758}, {x -> 10.8828, y -> -10.472}, 
>  {x -> 6.03128, y -> -6.28627}, {x -> 9.65888, y -> -8.38066}, 
>  {x -> 8.47911, y -> -10.4689}, {x -> 4.85152, y -> -8.3745}}
> ```

Comment: When I copy and paste your first block of code into a fresh notebook it still takes forever to compute? However the '// N // Chop' was a very useful addition. I just include a Round[a*b,0.000001] etc for each prefactor and it works :)

Comment: @ThomasJebbSturges. The important change was `theta = 1/10; phi = 1/10;`. With this change, solving your equations takes about 4 seconds on my system.

Comment: Hmm no, if i copy and paste your first block of code it still takes forever. I'm on version 8 which could be a reason.

Comment: @m_goldberg you can simply write `sol /. {C[1] -> 1, C[2] -> 2}`

Answer (score 1):

Below is something that works in V8.0.4.  Apparently something in [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Solve.html) was improved in V9, even though the docs indicate it was last modified in V8.

```
theta = 0.1; phi = 0.1;
a = 1 - 3 Sin[theta]^2*Cos[phi]^2;
b = 1 - 3 Sin[theta]^2*Cos[phi - (2 Pi/3)]^2;
c = 1 - 3 Sin[theta]^2*Cos[phi - (4 Pi/3)]^2;
Chop @ N @ Solve[
  TrigExpand @ Rationalize[
    a*b*Sin[(Sqrt[3] x - 3 y)/2] == a*c*Sin[(Sqrt[3] x + 3 y)/2] == -b*c*Sin[Sqrt[3] x],
   0],
 {x, y}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information. >>

```
(*
  {6.69512,
   {{x -> 0, y -> 0}, {x -> 0, y -> -6.28319}, ... {x -> 1.22392, y -> -6.2801}}}
*)
```

*Comments*:

The **`Solve::ifun`** warning indicates that `Reduce` might be a better function to use.  `Reduce` will give all the solutions with `C[1]`, `C[2]` parameters. Just replace `Solve` with `Reduce`, or use the option `Solve[..., Method -> Reduce]`.  You can be confident that roots are not missed.

**`TrigExpand`** seems to break the terms down into easier-to-chew bites, probably because the arguments to the trigonometric functions become either `(Sqrt[3] x)/2` or `y/2`, which might make it easier to isolate `x` or `y`.  (It would by hand, which led me to try it.)

**`Rationalize[..., 0]`** turns the approximate real numbers into rational numbers, which have an exact representation.  As [@m_goldberg](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/3066/m-goldberg) observes in an answer, `Solve` usually happier with exact numbers.

*Unexplained*

[@m_goldberg's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/3066/m-goldberg) solution, to use exact numbers for `theta` and `phi`, does not work in the above. My only guess is that the coefficients `a`, `b`, and `c` have such complicated exact expressions that `Solve` has a difficult time with them.

I also cannot explain why it works with the rounded coefficients.  It seems highly unlikely to me that decimal places have a role in trigonometric functions or numbers that internally are represented in binary.

Comment: Mr. Goldberg's solution works perfectly with 9.0. Please _Explain_ your _Unexplained_.

Comment: @eldo Did you try m_goldberg's `theta = 1/10; phi = 1/10;` in **my** code (= "the above")?

Comment: Will try later - now it's soccer time in good  old europe :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out (I think). It takes longer to compute depending on the number of decimal points. So I just used `Round[a b,0.000001]`, etc. to keep the digital places down.